# Hemicompact spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I want to know if hemicompactness is preserved during homeomorphisms. In other words, can we say that hemicompactness is a topological property?

Comment: Do you mean that if $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic and $X$ is hemicompact, then so is $Y$? If so, isn't that immediate from the definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule of thumb for me is "every property that can be defined purely in terms of set theory notions and open sets is a topological property". So yes.

Formally we can check this by proving:

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a homeomorphism. If $X$ is hemicompact then so is $Y$.

So let $K_n$, $ n \in \Bbb N$ be a cofinal compact sequence in $X$. Then define $K'_n=f[K_n] \subseteq Y$, which is compact as $f$ is continuous.

If then $C \subseteq Y$ is compact, then $f^{-1}[C]$ is compact in $X$ (as $f^{-1}$ is continuous) and so $f^{-1}[C] \subseteq K_m$ for some $m$ and then $C=f[f^{-1}[C] \subseteq f[K_m]=K'_m$ and so $\{K'_n: n \in \Bbb N\}$ is a cofinal compact sequence in $Y$ and so $Y$ is hemicompact.